# Is there a single word to describe a person or the quality of being obsessed with social approval?

Tags: single-word-requests, social-interaction

I am thinking in particular of being willing to demean or damage oneself to seek social approval. For example, a person who refuses to stand up for a friend when that friend is insulted by higher-status strangers, or maybe even pretend not to have that friend, in order to curry favour or avoid trouble.

Comment: ***Spineless**?* A [***gutless wonder**?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+gutless+wonder%22)

Comment: If there isn't a word, there should be one. Good question. I think spineless and gutless is part of how I'd perceive them, but it misses out the kowtowing element. And kowtowing misses out that element of betrayal.

Answer (score 2):

The word I think of based on your description is a:

> **Conformist**
>
> a person who conforms to accepted behavior or established practices.

...or someone who is **subservient** to society.

Comment: **Fake** is another word that comes to mind

Answer (score 0):

**vainglorious**  [vacabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/vainglorious)

> If you admire yourself in the mirror all the time and constantly brag
>   about all the beauty contests you have won, you might rightfully get
>   accused of being vainglorious.
>
> A vainglorious attitude is not very likable in a person and can be
>   annoying to be around. Vainglorious people are vain, excessively
>   boastful, and have swelled pride. The base word, vainglory, dates all
>   the way back to the 14th century and means “worthless glory.”

As in:

> Was he trying to appeal to every demographic, transcend every identity
>   category in a vainglorious effort to reach greater commercial heights
>   ...  The GuardianMar 16, 2018

Comment: I thought about the word **narcissist**, but that (along with **vainglorious**) describes someone who is obsessed with themselves; not necessarily how others perceive them. You can be *depressed*, but still want others to think highly of you.